# how to play sf/sfp?

Tags: sheet-music, dynamics, articulation, accent

I'm a bit confused what sf and sfp mean.
do they mean to suddenly play forte/loud, or to simply play an accent, or both?

and are all the following notes after sf supposed to be played forte?

for example in this mozart piece, in the 2nd bar there is a sf on the first beat, then there is a piano marking 1.5 the way through the bar, beneath the e,g and c sharp chord. are you suppose to play the notes in the first half of the 2nd beat as forte?

if sf means to play forte, is the only difference between it and simply a 'f' marking, is that you are suppose to play the first note with the marking with a strong accent too rather than simply loud, and the following notes loud, or also them acceneted?